# How do I use Xerces w/ in a Windows environment?

Tags: c++, xerces

I have downloaded the source for Xerces and am trying to use it in a Greenhills project. I get the following error:

could not open source file "xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp"

The code where the error hit is commented as:

```
// If the next line generates an error then you haven't run ./configure
#include    <xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp>
```

How do I run "./configure" in a windows environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't you will have to install some unix like environment like Cygwin.

Comment: Based on a casual glance, this appears to be extremely untrue.
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/ Unless you're talking about ./configure. You should clarify.

Comment: the question is "How do I run "./configure" in a windows environment?"

Answer (score 2):

To build Xerces with VSC++ on Windows you can use the supplied Visual Studio project files as described here:
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html#Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line to include "Xerces_autoconf_config.msvc.hpp" instead of "Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp". The header carries the configuration macros for Windows.